# Full DarkTheme for Spyder

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

So I read in this Reddit post [https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/4uoyce/spyder_color_scheme/] that there's an option for Spyder to be fully dark themed.

Unfortunately, since I'm very rookie, I was unable to install it.
Here's what I've done:

- Spyder Version 3.3.4 (miniconda)
- pip install qdarkstyle
- Since I don't have any spyderlib/spyder.py, I searched for something similar: Spyder-script.py but this file does not have "MAIN_APP = qapplication()".

Any help, pls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) A full dark theme will be part of Spyder 4, to be released later in 2019.

If you want to try it right now, you will need to install Spyder 4 **beta2**, the first version to have it available and which is going to be released on May 15/2019.

The instructions to use this beta can be found [here](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/releases).

Comment: I followed the instructions but I couldn't find any option to change it to dark theme. I saw an image where the preferences window has an "interface" menu, but this was not present in my Spyder. Has there been a change to this or something?

Comment: No, and the dark theme is now the default, so you should see it right after starting Spyder. So I guess you didn't follow the instructions correctly.

Answer (score 0):

On Spyder3 this worked for me (sorry for missing credits, I do not remember where I found it):

1. `pip3 install qdarkstyle`
2. `sudo gedit /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py`
   (or search for the good path: `locate mainwindow.py`)
3. at line 3109, before "return app" (followed by class Spy()), insert:

   ```
   import qdarkstyle
   app.setStyleSheet(qdarkstyle.load_stylesheet_pyqt5())
   ```
4. restart spyder3